# Integration of $x/\sqrt{x^2-7}$ using trigonometric substitution

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

Didn't find this one here so I'm asking away:

[image]

I tried integrating by substitution by ended up with just $x + C$ which is clearly wrong.

My work, as requested:

[image]

Comment: Please show your working, then someone can tell you what you did wrong.

Comment: And there is no need of a trig substitution. There's a very obvious substitution you can use.

Comment: @PranavArora, that's one of the reasons I suggested the OP show some working ;-)

Comment: This calls for a secant substitution if you wish to use that method. Let $x=\sqrt{7}\sec \theta$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- $$\dfrac{1}{2}\int\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-7}}(2xdx)=\dfrac{1}{2}\int\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-7}}d(x^2-7)=?$$
- $$\int\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-7}}dx=\dfrac{1}{7}\int\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{7}}\right)^2-1}}dx=\dfrac{1}{i}\int\dfrac{\frac{x}{\sqrt{7}}}{\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{7}}\right)^2}}d\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{7}}\right)\\
  =\dfrac{1}{i}\left(\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{7}}\right)\arcsin\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{7}}\right)-\int \arcsin \left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{7}}\right)d\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{7}}\right)\right)$$
  Which is what you'd get if you wanted integration by trig substitution (I don't know *why* you'd want it, but that's not my business).

Comment: I wish to do this via trig substitution.

Comment: @Guest See my edit.

Comment: Thank you, makes sense now.

Answer (score 4):

One way:
Let $u=x^2-7$, then $du=2x\ dx.$

Trig Substitution way:
Let $x=\sqrt 7\sec\theta$.  Then $dx=\sqrt 7\tan\theta\sec\theta.$  Also, $x^2=7\sec^2\theta.$  Plugging this in into the integral we have
$$\sqrt 7\int\frac{\sqrt 7\sec\theta}{\sqrt{7(\sec^2\theta-1)}}(\tan\theta\sec\theta)d\theta$$
$$\sqrt 7\int\frac{\sec^2\theta\tan\theta}{\tan\theta}d\theta=\sqrt 7\int\sec^2\theta d\theta=\sqrt 7\tan\theta+C$$
Since $x=\sqrt 7\sec\theta$, then $\sec\theta=\frac{x}{\sqrt 7}=\frac{\text{hypotenuse}}{\text{adjacent}}$.  This means that $\tan\theta=\frac{\sqrt{x^2-7}}{\sqrt 7}$.  Thus the answer is
$$\sqrt{x^2-7}+C$$

Comment: Thats not a hint, that is pretty much the answer, since what people who are studying this are learning is substitution.

Comment: There is no reason for a downvote.  If the OP is really struggling with integration, then this will serve its purpose for a hint, and does not give the answer away.

Comment: For what I've seen from people learning substitution, the part where they have most problems (and therefore potential for active learning) is figuring out what substitution to use. Based on that you are giving the answer, but if the problem is with the integration itself you are correct, so I'll remove the downvote. Please make an edit to the answer so I can remove the downvote (stack doesn't let me remove it)

Comment: To clarify, I already know to to solve this problem via substitution, I wish to do it via trig substitution

Comment: Edit coming momentarily...

Comment: I was wondering if someone was actually going to post some actual trig sub on this page like the OP originally wanted to see. :)

Comment: @J.W.Perry Yeah. It's bedtime for the kids so...it took me a minute to get back to it

Comment: @IvanLerner Oh yeah, post has been edited...feel free to remove downvote if you want to.

Comment: @Guest See my edit for a much simpler way not involving complex methods.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, no need to use trigonometric substitution. In fact,
$\int\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 - 7}}dx =\dfrac{1}{2}\int\dfrac{2x}{\sqrt{x^2 - 7}}dx  = \dfrac{1}{2}\int\dfrac{d(x^2 - 7)}{\sqrt{x^2 - 7}}dx = \sqrt{x^2 - 7}$ + C

Remark $\int{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{u}}}du = \int u^{-1/2}du = \dfrac{u^{1/2}}{1/2} + C = 2\sqrt{u} + C$.

Comment: This is from far away the simplest approach ! Why do you try to make life more complex than it is ?

Comment: The OP was not looking for the simplest way to solve the integral, he was trying to learn a new method, and sometimes applying a new method to an integral one already knows can be useful. To quote the OP in other comments "*To clarify, I already know to to solve this problem via substitution, I wish to do it via trig substitution*". Note however that the answer that made the most sense to him has me wondering about my ability to ascertain what anyone wants with certainty.

Comment: I agree with you in applying the technique of trigonometric substitution in other types of integrals. A good exercise is to use trigonometric substitution to evaluate the integral below instead of using partial fractions.  $\int \dfrac{1}{1 - x^2}dx$